# Azure Event Subscription - Filters Case Sensitive or Not Case Sensitive

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

It appears that Azure Event Subscription Filters  are not case sensitive. Currently I have got a filter created:
[image]

However in the Valid keys says all lower case, however the filter works "eventType" also the documentation indicates. In this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering
For events in the Event Grid schema, use the following values for the key: ID, Topic, Subject, EventType, DataVersion, or event data (like data.key1).

Currently it works, however, there are few in the team wanting to find out what is the recommended approach. Does anyone know the preferred way, or is this a documentation error.

Comment: Literally the first sentence in the screenshot tells: *All string comparisons are case-insensitive* It is a matter of preference whether you put in only lowercase keys or not.

Comment: @PeterBons - Thanks, I understand it's case-insensitive. My question is there preferred/recommended way? In one instance indicates all lower case and then in another part of the documentation it's all in capitals. I wasn't the only one asking this question in my organisation.